# Twitter ID to Twitter Handle lookup

Tags: python, twitter

Now that Twitter has closed its content to users that are not logged in...

Is it still possible to look up a Twitter Handle from a Twitter ID?

What I tried:

- When I tried to retrieve `https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=X` I get redirected to the login page.
- When I [tried](https://web.archive.org/web/20220127085009/http://metadatascience.com/2013/08/13/how-to-get-twitter-username-from-twitter-id/) to look up using `https://twitter.com/account/redirect_by_id?id=X` I get back from the server: `Hmm...this page doesn’t exist. Try searching for something else.`

How can I circumvent this, or should I somehow make my python script log into the twitter site first? Although that seems too cumbersome, as it probably needs verification of the browser via SMS.

Comment: You may be better off housing their API https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api . If you don't want it, sure you can use login method. I don't have twitter but isn't there a way to disable MFA?